# Console is Not printing properties defined in contructors in c#

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I have created a constructor inside a class(class Car) with 4 parameters.
I have assigned these parameters with the properties of the class.
But After creating an instance of that class i am not able to print them on the
Console.The console is printing just 0.Please help why it is not printing the properties.

```
 static void Main()

    {
        Car mycar=new Car("Bmw","bmwxi",2009,"silver");

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}",
        mycar.Make, mycar.Model, 
        mycar.Year, mycar.Color);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

And the class:

```
class Car
{

    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year     { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public Car (string make,string model,int year,string color)
    {
        make = Make;
        model = Model;
        year = Year;
        color = Color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor is backwards.
You are populating the arguments with the properties, should be the other way around:

```
public Car (string make,string model,int year,string color)
{
    Make = make;
    Model = model;
    Year = year;
    Color = color;
}
```

The Console is printing `0` because that's the default value of `int`.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)